# How do I fix position fixed overlap error?

Tags: html, css

My problem is when I used `position fixed` to fill up field environment, in mobile, the first div which is located in `goaloneimg` div is falling the second div located in `goalontext`. How do I fix this responsiveerror about `position fixed`

HTML codes

```html
<div class="goals">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="goalonetext">
                      <h1>What our goals?</h1>
                      <hr align="right" />
                      <p>Aliquam tempus lacinia quam sit amet</p>
                      <br/>
                      <p class="prightgoals">Aliquam tempus lacinia quam sit amet maximus. Donec tincidunt dui ut purus cursus lacinia.</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="goaloneimg">
                    <img src="http://www.infolab.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/work-and-coffee.jpg" />
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

CSS codes

```
.goals{
margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.goals > .row{
    height: 300px;
}

.goaloneimg img{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 419px;
}

.goalonetext{
    background-color: #54b4e6;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 30px 30px 0px 30px;
    height: 419px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Would you like the second div to display below the first? Or would you like the second div to appear directly on top of the first?

Comment: Yes. I would like to display the second div below first.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a media query to change the position attribute once you get to a certain width.  For example if the error starts to occur at 600px you will need to add this code( you can adjust the width in the media query.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .goaloneimg img, .goalonetext {
    position:initial;
  }
}
```

See working fiddle here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/Nimral/uv8yrrav/9/

Comment: I tried those codes. Also I changed to fix responsive error. So, when I used those codes, in mobile, the other divs which one I typed after them, those divs positing on goals divs. I am so confused..